# Predicting with time as covariate

Tags: r, prediction, generalized-additive-model

I have an indicator (intervention coverage in %) where data stop in 2015 and I would like to extrapolate/project data till 2018.

I have used the following code that basically predicts data using glm with time as covariate in the logit space.

My colleagues think a GAM model would be better but I don't see what would be the added value. Could you explain what would be the difference and which model would be best to use?

```
df_na <- df3 %>%
  filter(!is.na(y))

func <- function(data,country){
  data = subset(data,iso3==country)
  data[match(2010:2015,data$year),]$y
}

proj <- function(y, year=2010:2015, target=2018){
  period <- year[1]:target
  yhat <- predict(glm(y ~ year, family=quasibinomial), newdata=data.frame(year=period),type="response") 
  return(data.frame(year=period, y=yhat))
}

res <-   lapply(unique(df_na$iso3),function(i){
  data.frame(country=i,proj(func(df_na,country=i)))
})

res <- do.call(rbind,res)
```

Comment: GAM is used to model the logodds as a nonlinear function of year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your logistic model with `year`, time is assumed to act linearly on the logodds. With an additive model estimated with `gam`, a smooth action replaces the linear action, represented with a spline function. That gives a nice test on the assumption of linearity.

But, you want to use the model for extrapolation? A spline model will not help much with that ... you would first have to extrapolate the spline, how? On the other hand, if the `gam` model shows that linearity does not hold, using the linear model for extrapolation would be foolhardy. So that's your answer: The `gam` model mostly is a useful test (informal) on your first model.